# Debugging a c# application in WinDbg

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, windbg

I am trying to debug an application written in C#, on a system where I do not have Visual Studio. The application is not crashing... But I need to determine the values of certain variables, and whether certain parts of the code are accessed, based on a driver that I cannot have access to in the same location where Visual Studio is located.

I am running this test environment in a Virtual machine, with no internet access. I have been unable to install symbol file... but that has been irrelevant so far.

I have been troubleshooting the driver (c/c++) using WinDbg, attached to this application. I was hoping to be able to send debug messages to WinDbg as well, from C#.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("hello world\n");
```

Did not show up... I don't know if related, but the only different thing that I noticed when adding a Debug.Write was a new exception that I have not seen without the debug calls... (which try to display very innocent variables)

```
(c78.808): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(c78.808): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(c78.808): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
```

How can I send these messages to WinDbg output attached to this application in C# ?

Comment: is the application compiled with debug on? Because `Debug.Write` line has a `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`

Comment: You could run [DbgView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx) to view Debug.Write() statements.  You could use Visual Studio [Remote Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) instead of WinDbg.

Comment: Thanks I will try DbgView... The Visual Studio Remote Debugging sounds like a great idea, but I peeked at requirements and ... the only way the host can communicate with the VM is through a share or through clipboard. I cannot have it on the network.

Comment: What VM are you using?  I think VMware Workstation lets you create a network connection from the host to the guest only, it does not let the guest have a real Internet connection.  Don't know if that is acceptable or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using  [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx), that should show your debug messages and it has no dependencies, make sure you capture global win32 events and that Visual Studio hasn't got itself attached though.

Answer (score 1):

in your project properties **check mark BOTH** `DEFINE TRACE constant and DEFINE DEBUG constant`

Debug.WriteLIne as well ad Trace.Writeline output will be visible in windbg

code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("we should see both Debug and Trace .WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("This is From Debug.WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is From Trace.WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("This is From Debug.WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is From Trace.WriteLine\n");
            Console.WriteLine("watched 2 Dbg and 2 Trace WriteLine in windbg\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("This is From Debug.WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is From Trace.WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("This is From Debug.WriteLine\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is From Trace.WriteLine\n");
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
:cdb -c "g;q" helloWorld.exe | grep -i WriteLine
we should see both Debug and Trace .WriteLine
This is From Debug.WriteLine
This is From Trace.WriteLine
This is From Debug.WriteLine
This is From Trace.WriteLine
watched 2 Dbg and 2 Trace WriteLine in windbg
This is From Debug.WriteLine
This is From Trace.WriteLine
This is From Debug.WriteLine
This is From Trace.WriteLine
```